# How to send headers from Pentaho DI to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, kafka-topic

I have a need to pass Kafka headers (key-value pairs that can be attached to Kafka messages to provide metadata and additional information about the message) to send a JSON message to a topic.
Please tell me how can I do this in Pentaho 9.2?

[My transofrmation with "Kafka producer" step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNBt9.png)

[My "Kafka producer" step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geqDQ.png)

I did try sending JSON-message without required Headers and getting Error:
"Description":"Message for the ...., the value of the ... parameter: Must not be empty".

[My "Kafka consumer" step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6YIj.png)

Comment: Please, help me.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @millerluki 
I can't attach images any other way, what can I do about it?